# Setting IntelliSense's default exception type

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

In Visual Studio 2010 if I type `th` then press TAB twice, I will get:

```
Throw New ApplicationException("Exception Occured")
```

But in Visual Studio 2012 if I do the same thing, I will get:

```
Throw New ArgumentException("Exception Occured")
```

So the default exception type for IntelliSense has changed from ApplicationException to ArgumentException. Is this customizable? Is it possible to change the default intellisense exception type in Visual Studio 2012 to ApplicationException?

FYI plain vanilla Visual Studio without ReSharper / CodeRush / etc.

Comment: You took the words out of my mouth...I was going to recommend ReSharper. I'm surprised that 2012 defaults to ArgumentException. I would have expected it to be in alpha orderr. I thinking it can't be done outside of a plugin of some type.

Comment: @Gizmo *I would have expected it to be in alpha order* LOL **It is alpha order. :D** Read *that* one way to fast. However, I don't know about how that works in with the change in the settings files in the program's files... not mentioning how Application is used more (well for me, that is).

Comment: Personally, I try to avoid using Application Exception unless there is a compelling business related reason to do so but that is pretty much personal preference rather than best practice. You might want to check your alphabet though...He said that it used to default to App but was now defaulting to Arg..My understanding is that P comes before R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply edit VS2012Path\Vb\Snippets\1033\common code patterns\exception handling\ThrowanException.snippet

changing

```
<Default>ArgumentException</Default>
```

to

```
<Default>ApplicationException</Default>
```